# PostgreSQL: what is the difference between float(1) and float(24)?

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, precision, sqldatatypes, floating-point-precision

I am having a hard time understanding the precision parameter p for `float(p)` in PostgreSQL. For example, `float(1)` and `float(24)` seem to be exactly the same to me.

Can anyone provide me with some examples of their differences, please?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's in [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT):

> PostgreSQL also supports the SQL-standard notations float and float(p)
>   for specifying inexact numeric types. Here, p specifies the minimum
>   acceptable precision in binary digits. PostgreSQL accepts float(1) to
>   float(24) as selecting the real type, while float(25) to float(53)
>   select double precision. Values of p outside the allowed range draw an
>   error. float with no precision specified is taken to mean double
>   precision.

However, the key thing here is that it specifies the *minimum* acceptable precision. PostgreSQL uses this to select the underlying data type (`float4` or `float8`) that meets the requirement.

```
regress=> \x
Expanded display is on.
regress=> SELECT
        '1.123456789123456789'::float,
        '1.123456789123456789'::double precision,
        '1.123456789123456789'::float(1),
        '1.123456789123456789'::float(2),
        '1.123456789123456789'::float(24),                                                                                                                                     
        '1.123456789123456789'::float(48);                                                                                                                                     
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------                                                                                                                                                      
float8 | 1.12345678912346
float8 | 1.12345678912346
float4 | 1.12346
float4 | 1.12346
float4 | 1.12346
float8 | 1.12345678912346
```

You can use `pg_typeof` to confirm the type selections.

Effectively it's just there to support the standard syntax and gets translated into PostgreSQL's dialect - through selection of appropriate types - where it's used.

Comment: It means that float(1 ~ 24) are the same thing for PostgreSQL. So are float(25 ~ 53). Am I correct?

Comment: @DenLi Yes, you are correct. They're translated into `float4` or `float8` as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and examples. That is exactly what I asked for.

Comment: and `double pricision` and `float8` are the same, right guy?